# Найти промежуточные значение между названиями дней недели

Tags: javascript

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как найти значения недели между сокращениями дней недели:

```
Что-бы для SUN-WED получить SUN,MON,TUE,WED
или для MON-FRI получить MON,TUE,WED,FRI.
```

UPD: мой вариант

```
function getWeekDays(start, end) {
  let newarr = [];
  let week = ['SUN', 'MON', 'TUE', 'WED', 'THUR', 'FRI', 'SAT', 'SUN', 'MON', 'TUE', 'WED', 'THUR', 'FRI', 'SAT'];
  let a = week.indexOf(start);

    for (let i = 0; i < week.length; i++) {
      if (i >= a) {
        newarr.push(week[i])
        if (week[i] === end) {
          break;
        }
      }
    }
}

getWeekDays('SAT', 'MON');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У Вас во втором варианте пропущен четверг.

Марина, так как Вы уже не первый раз пользуетесь помощью сообщества `stackoverflow`, Вы должны понимать, что это не портал выполнения задач по требованию. 
Просто так за Вас никто не станет выполнять задачи, Вы же понимаете, что тут оказывают помощь, а не делают за Вас.

Постарайтесь в будущем обязательно прикладывать свои попытки выполнения задачи, тогда и минусов не будет, и гораздо больше будет вероятность, что Вам дадут быстрый и правильный ответ.

Добавил комментарии, чтобы было понимание, как всё это работает.

```js
let days = ['MON','TUE','WED','THU','FRI','SAT','SUN'];

let range = 'SUN-WED';
let range1 = 'MON-FRI';

function getRange(val) { // Объявляем функцию, которая принимает строку.
    let days1 = val.split('-'); // Разбиваем строку по -
    let dayFrom = days.indexOf(days1[0]); // Получаем индекс первого элемента в общем массиве дней
    let dayTo = days.indexOf(days1[1]); // Получаем индекс второго элемента в общем массиве дней
    let result = ''; // Сюда будем записывать результат

    if (dayTo<dayFrom){ // Если индекс второго параметра меньше первого, тогда...
        for(let i=dayFrom;i<days.length;i++){ // Делаем перебор с индекса первого параметра до конца массива дней(Чтобы попали все дни, даже, если они, например с пятницы по вторник)
            if(result){ // Если есть запись в строке результата то...
                result += '-'+days[i]; // ставим тире перед следующим параметром и добавляем его
            } else { // Если записи нет, то...
                result += days[i]; // Просто добавляем параметр
            }
        }
        for(let i1=0;i1<=dayTo;i1++){ // После того, как мы записали все дни с начала до воскреснья, нам необходимо записать остальные дни с понедельника до указанного параметра. Перебираем массив дней от 0 до индекса второго параметра
            if(result) { // Если есть запись в строке результата то...
                result += '-'+days[i1]; // ставим тире перед следующим параметром и добавляем его
            } else { // Если записи нет, то...
                result += days[i1];// Просто добавляем параметр
            }
        }
    } else { // Если же индекс второго параметра больше первого индекса, то...
        for(let i2=dayFrom;i2<=dayTo;i2++){ // Перебираем массив с индекса начала до индекса конца включительно
            if(result) { // Если есть запись в строке результата то...
                result += '-'+days[i2]; // ставим тире перед следующим параметром и добавляем его
            } else { // Если записи нет, то...
                result += days[i2]; // Просто добавляем параметр
            }
        }
    }
    return result; // Возвращаем из функции строку результата
}
console.log(getRange(range)); // Запускаем функцию и выводим результат в консоль.
console.log(getRange(range1)); // Запускаем функцию и выводим результат в консоль.
```

Или, если без объяснений и сократить код:

```js
    let days = ['MON','TUE','WED','THU','FRI','SAT','SUN'];
    let range = 'SUN-WED';
    function getRange(val) {
        let days1 = val.split('-');
        if (days.indexOf(days1[1])<days.indexOf(days1[0])){
            return days.slice(days.indexOf(days1[0]), days.length).join('-')+'-'+days.slice(0, days.indexOf(days1[1])+1).join('-');
        } else {
            return days.slice(days.indexOf(days1[0]), days.indexOf(days1[1])+1).join('-');
        }
    }
    console.log(getRange(range));
```

Comment: Спасибо большое!, я думала у меня это два цикла сделать получится. В том-то и дело что у самой вообще ничего внятного не получилось и показывать было не чего

Comment: как-то сложно все получилось

Comment: @Grundy Можно и гораздо короче, просто делал для разъяснения принципа работы. Добавил пример.